# Are unrelated high PR DO-FOLLOW Backlinks good for SEO?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks, dofollow

After reading multiple online blogs, forums I see that you can get DO FOLLOW back links from some highly trusted and rank webpages.

I have a website coming up very soon, ready to launch next month actually. And I really do not want to practice or entertain any kind of "Black Hat" SEO or anything else that could harm the websites in the future.

The website is a company that sells topsoil, gravel and compost FYI.

Now I have a few websites where I can get DO FOLLOW links from including:

1. Google Plus
2. Daily Motion
3. Reddit
4. Dribbble

I have a lot more on my list, but essentially these urls are between PR6 - PR 9 and can get me do follow backlinks. Are these backlinks good for me , even though they are not anything to do with soils, gardening etc...

Will google see it as me trying to spam sites for backlinks, or that im actually manually trying to get good backlinks?

Comment: First things first. PR for any page or site cannot be determined anymore and has not for quite a few years now. So through that away. As well, this list is a couple of years old. Anything SEO should be looked at more carefully if it is not from 2015/16. While these lists can be a jumping off point, do not thing G has not noticed them. Always do what makes sense. For example, the company can create a G+ page for their business. This makes sense. However, others may not. You have to decide. If you create just a few, then it is possible that G will not look too closely. Be wise not foolish.

Comment: Its all about quality of relevant links, not PR of links. You could have a million irrelevant high PR links and your site still ranks poorly due to weak relevancy, in fact these type of links will hurt if you have enough of them.  The links of Dribbble will only help you if your site is about 'design', Google+ 'posts', reddit, and dailymotion, are useless, as you need a lot of them and a lot of interaction. I highly recommend that you ditch the current SEO guide, or book your reading... and use information published in the last few years.

Comment: I would say it's amazing that people are still talking about PR but people are also still talking about meta tags so....

Comment: @JohnConde There is sooooooo much SEO junk out there confusing people who have no clue. That is why we get PR, Alexa, meta-tag questions and some of the other questions out there. Even MOZ has been at the center of some of these. The only thing I can think of is... the pay MUST be good! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're talking about thousands of spammy links, it definitely won't hurt your site rank.

It won't do any magic, but it can help your site to get recognized faster by crawlers.

My suggestion is to think about the bounce rate:
If someone actually clicked on one of these links, say from reddit, will he feel tricked and close the page right away? (high bounce rate) or will he stay and enjoy your website? (low bounce rate)

As long as you won't trick people, no harm will happen.
If you manage to get people to click and stay, you'll score some points.

Also, even though the websites you mentioned are not directly related to your site, I bet you can find pages in them that are related, such as a dailymotion video about soil.

Good luck with your new website!